# Facebook API: How to group and track down App Insights data using specified criteria?

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

In my customer's app I'm using FB API to track down App Insights analytics data. In the app we have some kind of items where each one represents particular app event. Currently we showing total App Insights data for each event. But we want to break that data down into data chunks that relates to corresponding events and want to show particular Insights data on particular events. So, I'm wondering is there any way to group FB App Insights data to retrieve analytics data for specified event? Maybe we can collect that data filtering all the posts out by specified hashtags or something. Any ideas?